# Updating related entities DDD

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I'm confused on how I'm going to updated related entities using DDD. Let say I have a Employee Class and Workschedule Class. How should I updated a specific workschedule of a certain employee? The relationship between Employee and Workschedule is One-To-Many. Below is the code I'm using how to Add/Update a certain workschedule.

```
public class Employee 
{    
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WorkSchedule> WorkSchedules { get; set; }

    public WorkSchedule AddWorkSchedule(WorkSchedule workSchedule)
    {
        this.WorkSchedules.Add(workSchedule);

        return workSchedule;
    }

    public WorkSchedule EditWorkSchedule(WorkSchedule workSchedule)
    {
        var originalWorkSchedule = this.WorkSchedules.FirstOrDefault(w => w.WorkscheduleId ==  workSchedule.WorkscheduleId);

        originalWorkSchedule.ClockIn = workSchedule.ClockIn;
        originalWorkSchedule.ClockOut = workSchedule.ClockOut;

        return originalWorkSchedule;
    }
}
public class WorkSchedule
{
    public int WorkScheduleId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ClockIn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ClockOut { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

Is this correct? Did I follow DDD correctly? Also, my thinking right now Workschedule is a value object but I'm putting and ID for normalization purposes

Answer (score 0):

your Model should be "POCO" class

CRUD methods such.. **Add** or **Edit** will be considored as part of "Service" or "Repository"

here is a quick idea that just came to my mind / how should it look like and its usage..

```
IRepository repository { get; set; } //implement Interface and inject via IoC Container

//..usage
var employee = repository.GetEmployee(123); //get by id
//..new WorkSchedule
employee.WorkSchedules.Add(workSchedule);

var result = repository.Save(employee);
```

Comment: I was thinking this method also but I'm confused since workschedule cannot exist without any employee thats why I created a Add Method on the Employee class. The Add method only add the workschedule on the list not on the DB

Comment: It's Model Validation (WorkSchedule.EmployeeId can't be NULL). you can use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` or implement `IValidatableObject` on your Model. so that `Save()` method can validate model before save. see [Entity Framework 4.1 Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959)

Comment: So you're saying its the same case with Orders and OrderLines

Answer (score 0):

Since everything here is EF related, it isn't much of DDD. IF the code works as desired, then it's ok. But DDD has no relationship to EF or any other ORM. You should design the Domain objects, without caring at all about the database or an ORM. Then, in the repository you map the Domain entities to Persistence entities which will be handled by the ORM.

> Also, my thinking right now Workschedule is a value object but I'm putting and ID for normalization purposes

This is the consequence when the layers and models are mixed. You don't need an ID in the domain  but you need an id for persistence. Trying to fit both requirements in one model and calling that model Domain leads to nowhere.

Comment: Actually I'm not pertaining to any ORM here, my DAL is pretty much extensible wherein I can implement NH, EF, etc. anytime. Thanks

Comment: Your code shown here clearly is tailored for an ORM, otherwise I don't understand why the WorkSchedules is virtual and has a public setter. Btw, there are no hard rules in DDD. THe rules are defined by the DOMAIN itself so you should know best if the code models the real life problem you want to solve. Also if the WorkSchedule is a value object, it should be invariable, so no public setters there.

Comment: Thank you Mike I think I see the "lightbulb" here

Answer (score 0):

EF it is not for DDD, it is too clumsy. EF is for same codemonkeys who likes t map SQL tables to Entities and do it like ActiveRecord antipatter, but after more intelligent developers started to call this as a bad practice, they started to use ORM, entities and continue monkeycoding.

I'm struggling with EF last 3 years to let it work DDD way. It successfully resists and wins. Without hacks it doesn't work. 
The on-to-many relations still doesn't work as expected, there is not way to create entities with constructor, not the public properties and so on.